# Content container to scroll from behind footer pulling the footer with it after it's cleared it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a fixed image background (this changes in a minute) with a content container that part scrolls up from behind the backgrounds footer, so splitting the background image from footer image or having a duplicate footer image, then, once the content container clears the footer image and aligns with goal posts (illustrated in link below) I want the background and footer to scroll together revealing the info on the footer. To explain the context of what i mean i've added some pics (via imageshack as I'm new to stack) that I thought would help illustrate it:

http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/94/b87i.png

html

```
     <body
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="content" style="background: #AAA;">     
                <div id ="sidebar">
                    <div id="sidenavbar">
                        <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs ul-menu">
                                <li class="side-menu1 active"><a href="#lA" data-toggle="tab">Home <i class="pull-right icon-home"></i></a></li>                                    
                                <li class="side-menu3"><a href="#lC" data-toggle="tab">Time <i class="pull-right icon-time"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="sidebar-tab-content tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="lA">
                                    <div class="tab-content-wrapper">
                                        <div class="side-header">
                                            <h2>HEADER</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="side-container">
                                        <h2>MENU 1</h2>
                                        <p>Quisque nec venenatis eros, sed cursus quam. Vestibulum dignissim cursus diam sed malesuada. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce consequat faucibus eros, eu congue massa. Nullam quam odio, mattis tincidunt ullamcorper vel, bibendum id lorem. In dignissim suscipit bibendum. Mauris porttitor libero vel tortor sodales, a congue ipsum iaculis. Morbi vulputate ipsum dictum eleifend molestie. Nulla facilisi. Nulla urna sem, fermentum eu purus non, placerat cursus eros. Sed vitae consectetur mauris, dignissim dictum quam. Morbi iaculis tincidunt lorem, id sodales nulla blandit nec. Integer hendrerit diam eget elit molestie, vitae laoreet erat malesuada.
                                        </p>
                                            </div>
                                        <div class="side-footer">
                                            <h2>FOOTER</h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p>FOOTER.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

css

```
            html, body {
            height: 100%;           
        }


        #wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%;            
            margin: 0 auto -60px;
        }

        #push, #footer {
            height: 60px;
        }

        .container-fluid {    
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #content {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 60px;
            top: 42px;
            right: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #sidebar {    
            position:absolute;
            width:300px;
            height:100%;                    
        }

        #sidebar .ul-menu {
            margin:0px;
        }

        #sidenavbar .tabs-left>.nav-tabs>li>a{    
            margin: 0px;
            min-width: 30px;
            width: 70px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
            border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
            border: 0px;
        }

        .sidebar-tab-content {
            background: #FFF;
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            left: 94px;
            width:100%;
        }

        #sidenavbar .tabs-left>.nav-tabs {
            border: 0px;
        }      

        #footer {
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #666;
        }

        .side-header, .side-footer {
            background: #AAF;    
        }

        .side-header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }
        .side-container {                
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 40px;
            top: 40px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .side-footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }

        h2 {
            margin: 0px;
        }
```

Here is a fiddle of where I got to:

http://jsfiddle.net/crispey/w6LP4/1/

Many thanks in advance, hope somebody is able to help,

C

so,after a few days with my Q on hold (not sure why now but not to worry??), and the odd person looking at my query, i decided to try it with a scrolling container as per my fiddle here:

(not enough rep for another link, so try this jsfiddle.net/crispey/vE6nv/)

either way, here is the markup:

```
<div class="textwrap">                
    <h1>Crispey Bears Sports Bar</h1>
    <h3>Purveyors of the finest free sports streams</h3>

<hr class="style-seven">

    <h4>Donec molestie molestie nulla vel placerat. Ut viverra in massa porttitor viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla diam nisl, euismod at erat eu, fringilla laoreet tellus. Praesent ut nulla quam. Ut vel elementum tortor, nec facilisis purus. Aenean dui odio, euismod adipiscing nisl eget, mollis ultrices dui.</h4>
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<hr class="line-four">
        <br><br>
    <h4><strong><em>IMPORTANT MESSAGE TO PARENTS! </em></strong> Donec molestie molestie nulla vel placerat. Ut viverra in massa porttitor viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla diam nisl, euismod at erat eu, fringilla laoreet tellus. Praesent ut nulla quam. Ut vel elementum tortor, nec facilisis purus. Aenean dui odio, euismod adipiscing nisl eget, mollis ultrices dui.</h4>
<hr class="line-two">

    <h5><strong><em>Disclaimer</em></strong> Donec molestie molestie nulla vel placerat. Ut viverra in massa porttitor viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla diam nisl, euismod at erat eu, fringilla laoreet tellus. Praesent ut nulla quam. Ut vel elementum tortor, nec facilisis purus. Aenean dui odio, euismod adipiscing nisl eget, mollis ultrices dui.</em> 
    <strong><em>Donec molestie molestie nulla vel placerat. Ut viverra in massa porttitor viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla diam nisl, euismod at erat eu, fringilla laoreet tellus. Praesent ut nulla quam. Ut vel elementum tortor, nec facilisis purus. Aenean dui odio, euismod adipiscing nisl eget, mollis ultrices dui.</em></strong></h5>
</div>
```

css - extra style that i've left in

```
textwrap {
width: 838px;
height:430px !important;
display: inline-block;
/* needed make it float in the middle of body */
margin: 20px auto 108px;
margin-left:252px;
padding: 20px 30px 0px 30px;
float: left;
text-justify: left;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
border: 2px solid #480a0a;
padding-bottom: px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #333;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #333;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #333;
background: #a8a8a8;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d9d9d9, #a8a8a8);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d9d9d9), to(#a8a8a8));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d9d9d9, #a8a8a8);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#d9d9d9, #a8a8a8);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#d9d9d9, #a8a8a8);
background: linear-gradient(#d9d9d9, #a8a8a8);
overflow:auto;
}
.textwrap h1 {
font-size: 30px;
text-align:left;
float: right;
color: #612b2b;
background-color: rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5);
text-shadow: 1px 1.6px 1px rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
font: bold 3.3em/1.5'BebasNeueRegular', trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) inset;
margin-right: 176px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right:10px;
}
hr.style-seven {
height: 30px;
margin-top:-21px;
margin-bottom:10px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
border-radius: 20px;
}
hr.style-seven:before {
/* Not really supposed to work, but does */
display: block;
content:"";
height: 30px;
margin-top: -51px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
border-radius: 20px;
}
.textwrap h2 {
font-size:20px;
text-align:left;
float:left;
clear:left;
color: #333;
text-shadow: 1px 1.6px 1px rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
font: normal 2.2em/2'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
}
.textwrap h3 {
font-size:18px;
text-align:center;
float:center;
clear:right;
color: #333;
text-shadow: 1px 1.6px 1px rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
font: bold 2.2em/2 Arial, Helvetica;
}
.textwrap p {
font-size:16px;
text-align: justify;
float:left;
color: #333;
text-shadow: 1px 1.6px 1px rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
font: normal'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
margin-top:-20px;
}
.textwrap h4 {
margin: -30px auto 0;
color:#403f3f;
font-size:18px;
text-align:justify;
float:left;
color: #333;
text-shadow: 1px 1.6px 1px rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
font:'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
font-weight:normal;
}
hr.line-one {
position:relative;
border: 0;
height: 1px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
margin:-1px 0px -20px 00px;
}
hr.line-two {
position:relative;
border: 0;
height: 1px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
margin:100px 0px -20px 00px;
}
hr.line-three {
position:relative;
border: 0;
height: 1px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
margin:50px 0px -20px 00px;
}
hr.line-four {
position:relative;
border: 0;
height: 1px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
margin:20px 0px 20px 00px;
padding: 0px 0 0 0;
}
.textwrap h5 {
color:#403f3f;
font-size:12px;
text-align:justify;
float:left;
color: #333;
text-shadow: 1px 1.6px 1px rgba(224, 224, 224, 1);
font: normal'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
margin-top:60px;
}
```

i would still love a solution to my first issue if anybody could take the time, or at least this question to be taken off hold so more people could check it out.

take care all and thanks again, v appreciated

C

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/about thoroughly to learn how to ask effective questions here. As it stands, your question lacks specifics and cannot be "correctly" answered.

Comment: "i'm not going to confuse the problem with my code" ... don't expect we do the code for you show some effort

Comment: You might get more help if you do provide some code or provide a fiddle (see: http://jsfiddle.net/) which will allow users to see what you have tried already.

Comment: @Blazemonger I've added html and css, made the text easier to read and to the point. I've also added a picture illustration and workings via js.fiddle.net. Please would you look at it again for me as I have attempted to lay it out as I perceive you require it to be done which I hope is ok for you to let it through, schoolboy errors, sorry :), thanks, Chris.